# Appointment's RecurrenceInfo gets lost

Tags: c#, devexpress, scheduler

I'm using the DevExpress scheduler control to make a readonly scheduler that shows customer's birthdays and some long term appointments.

I'm using my own viewmodel for the appointments that has all the appointment's properties e.g. AllDay, Label, RecurrenceInfo, ResourceId etc. and all of them are mapped by the AppointmentMapping, but when it comes to the RecurrenceInfo it is null; it shows the customer's birthday only on the date he was born and not yearly.

This is how I generate the RecurrenceInfo in the viewmodel's constructor (the only difference is that the viewmodel's recurrenceinfo is a string:

```
var recInfo = new RecurrenceInfo
{
    Type = RecurrenceType.Yearly,
    Periodicity = 1,
    Start = start,
    Month = start.Month,
    WeekOfMonth = WeekOfMonth.None,
    DayNumber = start.Day,
    WeekDays = GetWeekDays(start.DayOfWeek.ToString()),
    Range = RecurrenceRange.NoEndDate
};

this.RecurrenceInfo = recInfo.ToXml();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I just forgot to set the Appointment.Type to `Pattern`.